# d3js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am a newbie to d3. I'm pretty sure there is not an issue with my data. Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
(function() {

  d3.json("data.json", function(error, json){
    if(error) return console.warn(error);
    data = json;

    var format = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %Y")
    var amountFn = function(d){return d.amount}
    var dateFn = function(d){
      console.log(d.bonus);
      return format.parse(d.date)

    }


    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([10, 280])
      .domain(d3.extent(data, dateFn));

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([180, 10])
      .domain(d3.extent(data, amountFn));

    var svg = d3.select('#demo').append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", 300)
      .attr("height", 200)

    svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
      .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("cx", function(d){return x(dateFn(d.draw_date))})
      .attr("cy", function(d){return y(amountFn(d))})
  });


 })();
```

my data being retrieved is in the following formats.

```
[
    {
        "date": "2015-08-26T00:00:00",
        "amount": "30"
    },
    ...more data
]
```

Comment: `console.log(json);` Is it what you think? Where does the error occur exactly?

Comment: Where's your error line?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are doing many Silly minor mistakes here. with D3.js you must need to understand data structure.

In Your code i found many mistakes.

**1.** you stored your json in a variable which names data where you did'nt initialize it but it's ignore by javascript.

**2.** you passing in **console.log(d.bonus);** this key is not exist in your json so it's value showing as **"undefned"**. when you watching you console.

**3.** for your json data you need to convert d.date to date Object.

**4.** you already wrap your keys in x and y so you just need to pass

```
.attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.date); })
.attr("cy", function(d){return y(d.amount); })
```

instead of

```
.attr("cx", function(d){return x(dateFn(d.draw_date))})
.attr("cy", function(d){return y(amountFn(d))})
```

So i fix Some Errors in your code you can test this code by running on your system:

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head>    

<body>
<div class = "container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">D3 Test Example</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="demo"></div>
                <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my Script code is here..

```
    (function() {

      d3.json("data.json", function(error, json){
        if(error) return console.warn(error);
        var data = json;  // you store your json in data variable here..

        var format = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %Y").parse; // you don't need to this...
        var amountFn = function(d){return d.amount; };

        data.forEach(function(d){
            d.date = new Date(d.date); // you convert your d.date value in date string Object 
            d.amount = d.amount;
        });

        var dateFn = function(d){
          return d.date;
        }


        var x = d3.time.scale()
          .range([10, 280])
          .domain(d3.extent(data, dateFn));

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([180, 10])
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, amountFn)]);

        var svg = d3.select('#demo').append("svg:svg")
          .attr("width", 300)
          .attr("height", 200)

        svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()

          .append("svg:circle")
          .attr("r", 4)
          .attr("cx", function(d){ return x(d.date); })
          .attr("cy", function(d){return y(d.amount); })
      });

 })();
```

I used this data..

[
    {
        "date": "2015-08-24T00:00:00",
        "amount": "30"
    },{
        "date": "2015-08-25T00:00:00",
        "amount": "40"
    },{
        "date": "2015-08-26T00:00:00",
        "amount": "50"
    },{
        "date": "2015-08-27T00:00:00",
        "amount": "60"
    },{
        "date": "2015-08-28T00:00:00",
        "amount": "70"
    },{
        "date": "2015-08-29T00:00:00",
        "amount": "80"
    },{
        "date": "2015-08-30T00:00:00",
        "amount": "90"
    },{
        "date": "2015-08-31T00:00:00",
        "amount": "100"
    }
]

I hope this is the answer of your Question.
So my output is here...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for your help but I am not getting the following error.

Comment: Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="NaN"

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

1. In the format string, you have to add all the fields you're supplying to the format string. So you should use  `d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");` instead of `d3.time.format("%a %b %d %Y")`.
2. The `dateFn` function expects an object as parameter and not the date string. So replace `x(dateFn(d.draw_date))` with `x(dateFn(d))`.

Here is the working code snippet.

```js
var data = [{
    "date": "2015-08-26T00:00:00",
    "amount": "30"
}, {
    "date": "2015-07-26T00:00:00",
    "amount": "40"
}];

var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
var amountFn = function(d) {
    return d.amount
};
var dateFn = function(d) {
    console.log(d.bonus);
    return format.parse(d.date)
}


var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([10, 280])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, dateFn));

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([180, 10])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, amountFn));

var svg = d3.select('#demo').append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 200)

svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
    .append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(dateFn(d))
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(amountFn(d))
    })
```

```css
div{
   height: 800px;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```